# Cmake not using the right boost library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have two versions of boost:

- The first one (from xcode i guess) has files in `/usr/local/include/boost` and
  `/usr/local/lib/boost`
- The second one (from homebrew) has files in
  `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include/boost` and
  `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib`

As I want to use the second one, I call cmake to create my makefile and i compile my project this way:

```
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/ .
make
```

And I get this error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:54:17: error: 
  variable 'hash_value' declared as a template
std::size_t hash_value(std::list<T, A> const& v);
            ^
```

Clearly the boost version that is used is not the one I mentioned using `BOOST_ROOT` . How do I make sure that the version of boost that is used is the one in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/` ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the FindBoost cmake macro?

Comment: I have my own FindXXX.cmake files but not for boost. I count on FindBoost.cmake that cmake has already.

Comment: I am using this to find boost
`  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
  find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options regex REQUIRED)
      `

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have another dependency that requires `-I/usr/local/include/` in the flags, and that that `-I` flags is seen by the compiler before `-I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include`.

Debug your compilation process with:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

to see the compilation commands that are used.

Comment: I don't have any -I flags written manually as I am using Cmake. Thanks anyway

Comment: @IssamT. I mean that maybe you have used another CMake function `FindXXXX` where `XXX` is a library whose headers are installed in `/usr/local/include`. In that case, CMake adds `-I/usr/local/include` for you. Please check that hypothesis with `make VERBOSE=1`. I also use Homebrew, and that case happened to me, using CMake, and without manual flags.